# UDP Server on C# script in unity started but can't receive packets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, udp

I have an app on my android phone that sends a UDP packet with some information and I want to send this UDP packet to my Unity application. The android App works and sends the UDP packet (checked with wireshark) but somehow my C# script can't receive any. I googled and looked at similiar problems but none of them gave me an answer. I really don't know why it can't accept the packet.

I am broadcasting the UDP packet to make things easier but it doesn't seem to work. I also checked the ports.

Here is my C# code:

```
public class ControllerListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    Thread receiveThread;
    UdpClient client;

    public int port; 
    public string lastReceivedUDPPacket = "";
    public string allReceivedUDPPackets = "";

    public void Start()
    {
        init();
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj = new Rect(40, 10, 200, 400);
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj, "# UDPReceive\n127.0.0.1 " + port + " #\n"
                    + "shell> nc -u 127.0.0.1 : " + port + " \n"
                    + "\nLast Packet: \n" + lastReceivedUDPPacket
                    + "\n\nAll Messages: \n" + allReceivedUDPPackets
                , style);
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    // init
    private void init()
    {
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define port
        port = 5678;

        // status
        print("Sending to 127.0.0.1 : " + port);
        print("Test-Sending to this Port: nc -u 127.0.0.1  " + port + "");

        receiveThread = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();
    }

    // receive thread
    private void ReceiveData()
    {
        client = new UdpClient(port);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bytes empfangen.
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 5678);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                // Bytes mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Textformat kodieren.
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                // Den abgerufenen Text anzeigen.
                print(">> " + text);
                // latest UDPpacket
                lastReceivedUDPPacket = text;
                Thread.Sleep(8);
                Debug.Log("Hier");
                // ....
                allReceivedUDPPackets = allReceivedUDPPackets + text;

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                print(err.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    // getLatestUDPPacket
    // cleans up the rest
    public string getLatestUDPPacket()
    {
        allReceivedUDPPackets = "";
        return lastReceivedUDPPacket;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        if (receiveThread != null)
            receiveThread.Abort();

        client.Close();
    }
}
```

I just want to know why doesn't my code get out from the .Receive(...) method even though a UDP packet is broadcasted.

Thanks in advance (my first post on this site)

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`Udpclient.Receive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive) will block until a datagram arrives from a remote host.

So if it doesn't return it simply means nothing was received yet.

This can have multiple reasons.

Afaik for [`IPEndPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.ipendpoint.-ctor) you should probably rather use

```
IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
```

Which means the sender can have any IP address and send from any port. You limited the sender address to `Broadcast` which will probably never be the case since the sender can not have a broadcast adress. Also the senders outgoing port might not match `5678`. `0` allows the sender to send from **any port**.

---

Sidenote: [`Thread.Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep) is in milliseconds so using only `8` also looks a bit odd ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer...I changed it now but still nothing, it still can't get out from the udpClient.Receive(...) function...

Comment: this means nothing was received .. this can have a lot more reasons and is hard to debug without having more information. Try to not broadcast the package but send it directly to the correct cleint address.

Comment: for me it seems like a unity problem or something I am not aware of because I made a simple server in Java and it receives the broadcast and with the correct client address. What kind of additional information would you need?

Comment: thank you, I changed it and turned the firewall off and now it works :D